# Android - For loop with global static list vs local list

Tags: java, android

I was just wondering if there are any performance differences if I do the following, also are there any differences in RAM usage?

Instead of doing:

```
for (String str : Globals.stringArray)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

I do this:

```
List<String> stringArray = Globals.stringArray;
for (String str : stringArray)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

Would it be better to loop through a local list instead of a global static list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no (significant) performance difference, depending on the compiler, your code will likely result in the exact same bytecode, because you are iterating over the exact same object anyways. In general, you should not try to tune performance on such a low level, but choose the more readable, self-expressive approach instead:

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

(quote by Donald Knuth)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should perform exactly the same, as your local variable does not contain a copy of the global static, but a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

After your compiler optimized this code it result to the same in the intermediary language. So, no there won't be any difference at all.